# Does strong duality hold?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My problem:** For fixed $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$
$$
\text { minimize }(x-a)(x+b) \text { subject to }(x-c)(x+d) \leq 0 \text {. }
$$
Does strong duality hold?
**My attempt** For the case $c \ne -d$, I can check the strong duality by using Slater condition: Let's choose $x=\dfrac{d-c}{2}$. But when $c =-d$, the strong duality doesn't hold. I used to think about computing the $p^*$ and $d^*$ but it's very hard for computation.

Comment: For the case $c = -d$ your problem has a single feasible point (namely $x =  - d$). So at least computing $p^*$ is fairly straightforward.

Comment: yes. But computing d* is quite difficult